# Variable sleep bash alias

Tags: bash, alias, sleep

So, I'm trying to create an alias which will run a command after sleeping x seconds.

```
alias ls_sleep="sleep $1 && ls"
```

The problem is, $1 is being passed as string and things like $(($1)) or $(($1+0)) doesn't work.

Would it be possible to make it work in a single line without using a function?

Comment: Welcome, does [Insert a user defined variable in an alias in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497041/insert-a-user-defined-variable-in-an-alias-in-bash) answer your question?

Comment: "The problem is, $1 is being passed as string " -- no it isn't, variables and positional parameters are pretty much always strings. Try it with `alias ls_sleep="sleep $1; ls"` instead and, see if you can spot what happens. Aliases aren't functions and they don't act like such. If you have some reason you can't use a function instead, you might want to think very hard how valid it is...

Answer (score 2):

You can’t do this with an alias, but you can do it in a single line with a function:

```
ls_sleep() { sleep "$1" && ls; }
```